# Getter в Python

Tags: python, getter

Есть пример кода на Java, controlPoints и point - листы. 
Как будет выглядеть этот код на питоне?

```java
ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
ArrayList<Point2D.Double> controlPoints = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
//...
double[][] r2 = new double[controlPoints.size()][points.size()];
for (int k = 0; k < controlPoints.size(); k++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
    r2[k][i] = (Math.pow(controlPoints.get(k).getY() - points.get(i).getY(), 2)
              + Math.pow(controlPoints.get(k).getX() - points.get(i).getX(), 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: А какой тип у controlPoints и points? Какие типы они содержат в себе?

Comment: ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
    ArrayList<Point2D.Double> controlPoints = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Питоне, для обычных списков это должно выглядеть так:

```py
r2 = [[(cp.y - p.y)**2 + (cp.x - p.x)**2 for p in points]
      for cp in control_points]
```

где `Point2D` может быть [`collections.namedtuple('Point2D', 'x y')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (если специальных требований нет, то класс руками незачем писать).

В Питоне, принято использовать `.x` вместо `.getX()`. Если необходимо, то простой атрибут, можно позже на property заменить в Питоне, *не изменяя как объекты используются снаружи*.

```py
>>> import collections
>>> Point2D = collections.namedtuple('Point2D', 'x y')
>>> p = Point2D(1,2)
>>> p
Point2D(x=1, y=2)
>>> p.x
1
>>> p.y
2
>>> points = [Point2D(x, y) for x in range(2) for y in range(3)]
>>> points
[Point2D(x=0, y=0), Point2D(x=0, y=1), Point2D(x=0, y=2),
 Point2D(x=1, y=0), Point2D(x=1, y=1), Point2D(x=1, y=2)]
```

Если большая матрица с числами, то на Питоне обычно используется [`numpy`, `scipy`, etc](http://www.scipy.org/index.html). [Пример для 3D точек](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2486093/4279):

```py
d = ((a - point)**2).sum(axis=1)  # compute distances
```

Обратите внимание, что это векторная операция, которая вычисляет значения для миллиона точек в данном примере.

Answer (score 1):

В питоничьих класса также есть свойства, но в данной задачи с заданными условиями я не вижу смысла их использовать – полей класса хватит сполна.

Также, вместо создания своего класса можно использовать кортежи (`tuple`), или для удобства использовать именованные кортежи, они отличаются от обычных тем, что доступ к элементам в именованных осуществляется через поля, а не через индексы.

```
# Для большей схожести использую класс
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Point({}, {})>".format(self.x, self.y)


# Заполнение списков
controlPoints = [Point(i, i) for i in range(4)]
points = [Point(i + 1, i + 1) for i in range(2)]

# Первый вариант создания списка списков
r2 = list()
for i in controlPoints:
    sub_list = list()
    for j in points:
        sub_list.append(None)

    r2.append(sub_list)

# Второй вариант создания списка списков
r2 = [[None for j in points] for i in controlPoints]

import math
for k in range(len(controlPoints)):
    for i in range(len(points)):
        r2[k][i] = math.pow(controlPoints[k].y - points[i].y, 2) + math.pow(controlPoints[k].x - points[i].x, 2)
```