# Обработка нескольких массивов в матрицу Python

Tags: python, массивы, ооп, циклы, матрицы

Есть 4 листа с координатами точек и размерностями n и n-1:

```
 X[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],Y[0.0, 0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0],kX[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],kY[0.1667, 0.5, 0.8333]
 ## X,Y-координаты точек, kX,kY-координаты контрольных точек ##
```

Необходимо написать метод, который возвращал бы матрицу (3,4).

```
      ###запускаю цикл для формирования матрицы#####
      for k in range(0,3):
         for i in range(0,4):
     ### теперь суть вопроса - как можно обратиться к k-ому и i-ому элементам листов##
     ### X , Y , kX , kY - не открывая цикл for для каждого###
     то есть нужно получить массивы: 
      uk = [[kX[0]-X[0], kX[0]-X[1], kX[0]-X[2],kX[0]-X[3]],
      [[kX[1]-X[0], kX[1]-X[1], kX[1]-X[2],kX[1]-X[3]],
      .....]
      vk = [[kY[0]-Y[0], kY[0]-Y[1], kY[0]-Y[2],kY[0]-Y[3]],
      [[kY[1]-Y[0], kY[1]-Y[1], kY[1]-Y[2],kY[1]-Y[3]],
      .....]
```

На Java есть метод get(). Как можно решить этот вопрос на Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить элемент из i-ой строчки, в j-ой колонке в матрице, представленной вложенными списками: `matrix[i][j]`. Или `matrix[i,j]`, если matrix это двумерный numpy массив.

Чтобы создать списки списков uk, vk из вопроса, нет необходимости по индексам обращаться:

```
uk = [[kx - x for x in X] for kx in kX]
vk = [[ky - y for y in Y] for ky in kY]
```

Comment: Отлично! А если нужне массив : r = (kx - x)^2 + (ky - y)^2 ?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov [код такой же как я уже вам показывал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600125/23044) (представьте: `points = [Point2D(x,y) for x, y in zip(X,Y)]`). Если этот не ясно, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом, так как матрица - это массив массивов, а в нашем случае список списков, то сначала инициализируем главный список - *matrix*, а потом каждый раз добавляем строку, которая формируется во втором вложенном цикле *for*.

```
X = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Y = [0.0, 0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0]
kX = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
kY = [0.1667, 0.5, 0.8333]
def get_matrix(kL,L):
    matrix = list([])
    for k in range(0, 3):
        row = list([])
        for i in range(0, 4):
            row.append(kL[k] - L[i])
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix
print get_matrix(kY, Y)
```