# Работа с несколькими массивами в Python

Tags: python, массивы, циклы, методы

Есть массивы с точками:

```
X[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],Y[0.0, 0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0],
kX[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],kY[0.1667, 0.5, 0.8333]
```

Нужно сформировать двумерные массивы R2, U и V размера(3,4), элементы которых считаются по формулам:

```
r2 = math.sqrt(math.pow((kX[k]-X[i]), 2) + math.pow((kY[k]-Y[i] ) , 2))
u = 1 / (2 * math.pi) * ((kY[k]-Y[i]) / math.pow(r2[k][i], 2))
v = - 1 / (2 * math.pi) * ((kX[k]-X[i]) / math.pow(r2[k][i], 2))
```

Поскольку я новичек, меня особенно интересует подробное описание [следующего кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599962/getter-%D0%B2-python/600125#600125):

```
###псевдокод#### 
r2 = math.sqrt(math.pow((kX[k]-X[i]), 2) + math.pow((kY[k]-Y[i] ) , 2))
### реализация на питоне ####
r2 = [[(cp.y - p.y)**2 + (cp.x - p.x)**2 for p in points]
       for cp in control_points]
```

где используется  `collections.namedtuple` и вообще как обращаться к элементам массивов без использования циклов, желательно на этом примере.

Случай с точками двух массивов понятен:

```
u = [[1 / (2 * math.pi)*(kx - x) for x in X] for kx in kX] 
v = [[1 / (2 * math.pi)*(ky - y) for y in Y] for ky in kY]
```

А как быть, если  нужно:

```
u = [[1 / (2 * math.pi)*(kx - x) for x in X] for kx in kX] / r2[k][i]
v = [[1 / (2 * math.pi)*(ky - y) for y in Y] for ky in kY] / r2[k][i]
```

Comment: А можете написать явный код для r2,u,v? Особенно интересно, как с элементов 4 листов можно считать лист R2.

Comment: я добавил решение, которое использует numpy массивы. Посмотрите, есть ли у вас какие-либо комментарии.

Comment: Благодарю, все работает! Очень полезно было узнать про нампай тоже. Насколько я понял, в списках напрямую в массиве u и v элемент r2ki - это номер элемента строки, а r2k - столбца?

Comment: да, numpy для работы с массивами хорошо подходит. Посмотрите ещё на [`scipy.spatial.distance` модуль](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), который различные функции по вычислению пространственных метрик предоставляет, чтобы руками их заново не реализовывать.¶ r2k это ряд—не номера в ряду, это *сам* ряд в матрице r2. Попробуйте, `for r2k in r2: print(r2k)`. Аналогично, r2ki это не номер, это сам элемент. В моём ответе индексы вообще не используются. Если вы все элементы по порядку просматриваете, то нет необходимости по индексам обращаться. По практикуйтесь с...

Comment: ... с for-циклами в интерактивной консоле Питона.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Вы очень мне помогли!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать X, Y, kX, kY как Python-списки напрямую:

```
import math

r2 = [[((kx - x)**2 + (ky - y)**2)**.5 for x, y in zip(X, Y)] 
      for kx, ky in zip(kX, kY)]
u  = [[(kx - x) / (2 * math.pi * r2ki) for x, r2ki in zip(X, r2k)]
      for kx, r2k in zip(kX, r2)] 
v  = [[(ky - y) / (2 * math.pi * r2ki) for y, r2ki in zip(Y, r2k)]
      for ky, r2k in zip(kY, r2)]
```

`zip()` это встроенная в Питон функция:

```
>>> list(zip(range(3), "abc"))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Происхождение названия от [zipper](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)—застёжка-молния: `zip()` "сшивает" переданные аргументы.

### Point2D (collections.namedtuple)

Если:

```
points = list(map(Point2D, X, Y))
control_points = list(map(Point2D, kX, kY))
```

тогда код для `r2` идентичен [уже приведённому решению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600125/23044) (c точностью до вызова sqrt):

```
r2 = [[((cp.y - p.y)**2 + (cp.x - p.x)**2)**.5 for p in points]
      for cp in control_points]
```

Пример:

```
>>> import collections
>>> Point2D = collections.namedtuple('Point2D', 'x y')
>>> X, Y = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0]
>>> points = list(map(Point2D, X, Y))
>>> points == [Point2D(x, y) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
True
>>> points
[Point2D(x=0.0, y=0.0), Point2D(x=0.0, y=0.3333), 
 Point2D(x=0.0, y=0.6667), Point2D(x=0.0, y=1.0)]
>>> [p.y for p in points]
[0.0, 0.3333, 0.6667, 1.0]
```

### numpy

Eсли работать с X, Y, kX, kY как с numpy-массивами:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X, Y, kX, kY = map(np.array, [X, Y, kX, kY])
>>> r2 = ((kX[:,None] - X[None,:])**2 + (kY[:,None] - Y[None,:])**2)**.5
>>> r2
array([[ 0.1667,  0.1666,  0.5   ,  0.8333],
       [ 0.5   ,  0.1667,  0.1667,  0.5   ],
       [ 0.8333,  0.5   ,  0.1666,  0.1667]])
>>> u = (kX[:,None] - X[None,:]) / (2 * math.pi * r2)
>>> v = (kY[:,None] - Y[None,:]) / (2 * math.pi * r2)
>>> v
array([[ 0.15915494, -0.15915494, -0.15915494, -0.15915494],
       [ 0.15915494,  0.15915494, -0.15915494, -0.15915494],
       [ 0.15915494,  0.15915494,  0.15915494, -0.15915494]])
```

Здесь индексация с `None` добавляет новую размерность (из одномерного массива создаёт двумерный):

```
>>> kY
array([ 0.1667,  0.5   ,  0.8333])
>>> kY[:,None]
array([[ 0.1667],
       [ 0.5   ],
       [ 0.8333]])
```

Comment: Данные в массиве v некорректные (а значит и в массиве u). Нужно зафиксировать первый элемент массива kY и отнять его от всех элементов Y - получим первую строку [ 0.1591, -0.1591 , -0.4801 , - 0,7993  ] (считал в ручную). Для второй строки - втрой элемент от всех элементов Y и так далее . Что исправить, чтобы было так?

Comment: Использовал  метод numpy

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov Оба метода в ответе одинаковый результат дают (в соответствии с тем как эти массивы у вас в вопросе определены). Вы похоже забыли на `(2*pi*r2)` поделить.

Comment: r2 правильно посчитало, а v - нет, все так же, как вы рекомендовали.

Comment: Прошу прощения, все верно. Тут в формулах запутался.