# Как сделать, чтобы цикл проходил по индексам листов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 списка. Первый - это координаты x, второй - y. Надо найти расстояние между точками. Код написал так:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_list_1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
dist = []

for index in range(len(new_list)):
    x1 = new_list[index]
    x2 = new_list[index+1]
    y1 = new_list_1[index]
    y2 = new_list_1[index+1]
    distance_1 = ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
    dist.append(distance_1)
    index += 1

print(dist)
```

Comment: То есть вам просто нужно понять как пройти по индексам массива, а не по его элементам?

Comment: по элементам через индексы, к примеру x1 сначала 1, потом 2, 3 и до 5, x2 с 2 до 6

Comment: Делайте итерацию с шагом 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Я не вполне понял, что вы хотели сделать этой строчкой, но в любом случае в конце цикла бесполезно делать `index += 1`

`range` в любом случае будет перебирать все числа подряд от нуля, до верхней границы, вне зависимости от того, что вы делаете с переменной `index` внутри цикла. Вы можете её хоть на миллион умножить, всё равно `range` будет `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`

2). Я бы вашу задачу решал как-то так:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_list_1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


dst = lambda xy1, xy2: ((xy1[0] - xy2[0]) ** 2 +
                        (xy1[1] - xy2[1]) ** 2
                       )** 0.5

def pairs(seq1, seq2):
  itr = iter(zip(seq1, seq2))
  prev = next(itr)
  while True:
    cur = next(itr)
    yield (prev, cur)
    prev = cur

result = [dst(pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in pairs(new_list, new_list_1)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и помощь

Comment: Посмотрите на pairwise рецепт в [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools)

Answer (score 2):

> по элементам через индексы, к примеру  x1 сначала 1, потом 2, 3 и до 5, x2 с 2 до 6

Можно попарно соседние значения в списке обойти c помощью [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
xs =  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
for x1, x2 in zip(xs, xs[1:]):
    print(f"x1={x1}, x2={x2}")
```

[Результат](https://repl.it/JoXz):

```
x1=1, x2=2
x1=2, x2=3
x1=3, x2=4
x1=4, x2=5
x1=5, x2=6
```

Чтобы расстояние между точками на плоскости найти, можно объединить отдельные одномерные массивы для x, y координат в один список с 2D-координатами точек, снова используя [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ys = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
points = list(zip(xs, ys))
distances = [((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
             for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(points, points[1:])]
```

[Результат](https://repl.it/JoYv):

```
1.4142135623730951 1.4142135623730951 1.4142135623730951
1.4142135623730951 1.4142135623730951
```

Если вы часто с подобными данными работаете, то попробуйте `numpy` модуль. Пример: [Работа с несколькими массивами в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/601722/23044) (если вы решите только Питон-списки использовать, то посмотрите на использование [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) для улучшения читаемости кода в примере с помощью `Point2D`).

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю, да придётся теперь с картографическими данными работать.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае и этого будет достаточно:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(0:len(a)//2):
    lets_do_some_math(a[2*i],b[2*i],a[2*i+1],b[2*i+1])
```

само выражение типа : `for something in range(x,y)` означает, что something примет значения от `x` до `y-1`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и помощь

Answer (score 1):

Заметил опечатку у автора в `y1 = new_list_1[index]` и немного подправил код:

```
new_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_list_1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
dist = []

for index in range(len(new_list)):
    try:
        x1 = new_list[index]
        x2 = new_list[index + 1]

        y1 = new_list_1[index]
        y2 = new_list_1[index + 1]

        distance = ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** 0.5
        dist.append(distance)

    except IndexError:
        pass

print(dist)
```

Консоль:

```
[1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и помощь.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСвентицкий, если ответы считаете правильным отметите их галочкой, а если полезными то плюсом вверх ;)